# Easy way to tell if a string is contained in another string that is a comma delimited list

Tags: java, talend

I am working in Talend so need a one-liner if possible to determine if string1 is a value in string2 which is a comma delimited list.

For example `string1=foo` and `string2=foo,bar,red,green` it would be true.

I was using contains but the issue is it matches on `string2=fool,bar,red,green...` in this case I want false

Comment: use a regex built using string1 to add the qualifications that it be an element in the CSV

Comment: there could be more than one solutions..could you be specific which thing you want to focus on more?

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean result = Arrays.asList(string2.split(",")).contains(string1);
```

This is one approach, but depends on timeComplexity requirements as well. Using regex can be another approach

Answer (score 0):

Another option using regex is:

```
String string1 = "\\bfoo\\b";                
String string2 = "bar, foo ,red,green";        

System.out.println(Pattern.compile(string1).matcher(string2).find());
```